# Weird Response While Scraping Data Using Python Requests Library

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from "https://tradingtick.com/backtest/position-strategy-backtest.php" using Python's request library.

I am using the following code for scraping the list of expiries. The inputs has been obtained by inspecting the network tab of developer console. While I see the response in the developer's console, but my python script produces a weird encrypted (i assume) response.

Please help understanding the issue. Thank you !

Code -

```
    import requests

    strategy_backtest_url = "https://tradingtick.com/backtest/position-strategy-backtest.php"

strategy_backtest_header = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Host": "tradingtick.com",
    "Origin": "https://tradingtick.com",
    "Referer": "https://tradingtick.com/backtest/position-strategy-backtest.php",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64"
    }
   underlying = "banknifty"

   option_expiries = requests.post(strategy_backtest_url, headers = strategy_backtest_header, json = {"type":"expiry", "underlying":underlying})
```

Produces following output

```
print(option_expiries.text)

"\x03�\x00\x00D�M��7i��\x1f�%H\x04�� ���\x03�Y\x01\x06@\t'x@z\x07\x15����q���|��i�\x03�1�K:�\x02/j\x19\x1c�:48q�\x01%���\x1dА%ے�H�$�\t*�a\x00\x03"
```

Comment: The above code seems to be executing fine for me and i am able to see a list of expiry as the output.

Comment: Thats weird. Tried again. But gives above junk to me.

Comment: what's the python and request library version you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "*br*" in the "*accept-encoding*" line in your *strategy_backtest_header*

From:

```
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
```

To:

```
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"
```

If this does not help, try removing the "Accept-Encoding" line entirely to not request compression.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your encoding (in r.encoding) before calling r.text:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com')
r.encoding = 'utf-8'  # specify UTF-8 encoding
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Gives Following. Not Expected Data.......
b"\x03\xef\xbf\xbd\x00\x00D\xef\xbf\xbdM\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd7i\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x1f\xef\xbf\xbd%H\x04\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x03\xef\xbf\xbdY\x01\x06@\t'x@z\x07\x15\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbdq\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd|\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbdi\xef\xbf\xbd\x03\xef\xbf\xbd1\xef\xbf\xbdK:\xef\xbf\xbd\x02/j\x19\x1c\xef\xbf\xbd:48q\xef\xbf\xbd\x01%\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x1d\xd0\x90%\xdb\x92\xef\xbf\xbdH\xef\xbf\xbd$\xef\xbf\xbd\t*\xef\xbf\xbda\x00\x03"

Comment: try to specify it before call the r.text function